# Chrome Element Inspector Font

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts

Does anyone know what font is used for the chrome element inspector? I am trying to use the same on a webpage.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The view-source: uses the same font-family as the inspector.

And that font-family is

```
font-family: monospace;
```

Answer (score 0):

here is :https://www.cssfontstack.com/monospace

```css
p {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<p>font's chrome</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect the inspector using (on windows) CTRL+SHIFT+I.

Then you can inspect a single row and check which is the first font applied.

In my case the font is Consolas (and probably in your case too).

You may find [this thread](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-discuss/DCfo1X8GHyc) helpful.

[image]